# Zariski Cancellation and Toric Varieties, why isn't this affine variety toric?

Tags: toric-varieties

The Zariski cancellation problem asks the following.  If $ Y $ is a variety such that $ Y \times \mathbb{A}^{1}_{k} \cong \mathbb{A}^{n+1}_{k} $, then is $ Y $ isomorphic to $ \mathbb{A}^{n}_{k} $?

The variety $ \mathbb{A}^{n+1}_{k} $ is a toric variety.  Namely, there is a $ \mathbb{G}_{m}^{n+1} $-equivariant embedding of an $ n+1 $-dimensional torus in $ \mathbb{A}^{n+1}_{k} $.  For example, if $ \mathbb{A}^{n+1}_{k} \cong \operatorname{Spec}(k[X]) $, then $ D(\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} x_{i}) \cong \mathbb{G}_{m}^{n+1} $ and this acts on $ \mathbb{A}^{n+1}_{k} $ via $ ((a_{1},\dots,a_{n+1}),(b_{1},\dots,b_{n+1})) \mapsto (a_{1}b_{1},\dots,a_{n+1}b_{n+1}) $.

If $ \phi: \mathbb{A}^{n+1}_{k} \to Y \times \mathbb{A}^{1}_{k} $ is the isomorphism, and $ p_{1} $ is the natural projection from $ Y \times \mathbb{A}^{1}_{k} $ to $ Y $, then $ p_{1} \circ \phi \mid_{D(\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}x_{i})} $ is a dominant morphism from $ \mathbb{G}_{m}^{n+1} $ to $ Y $.  Let us denote its image by $ T_{Y} $.  Similarly, if $ p_{2} $ is the projection from $ Y \times \mathbb{A}^{1}_{k} $ to $ \mathbb{A}^{1}_{k} $, then $ p_{2} \circ \phi $ is a dominant morphism from $ \mathbb{G}_{m}^{n+1} $ to $ \mathbb{A}^{1}_{k} $.  Let us denote its image by $ T_{\mathbb{A}^{1}} $.

If $ \mu_{\mathbb{G}_{m}^{n+1}} $ is the action of $ \mathbb{G}_{m}^{n+1} $ on $ \mathbb{A}^{n+1}_{k} $, then $ \phi \circ \mu_{\mathbb{G}_{m}^{n+1}} \circ (\operatorname{id}, \phi^{-1}) $ is an action of $ \mathbb{G}_{m}^{n+1} $ on $ Y \times \mathbb{A}^{1}_{k} $.  This action is simply the product of the actions of $ T_{Y} $ on $ Y $ with the action of $ T_{\mathbb{A}^{1}} $ on $ \mathbb{A}^{1}_{k} $.

This seems to show that $ Y $ is a toric variety.  The ideal of an affine toric variety is a binomial ideal (i.e., each defining polynomial is the difference of two monomials).  In Neena Gupta's paper *On Zariski's Cancellation Problem in Positive Characteristic* Neena Gupta gives a counterexample to the Zariski Cancellation problem in positive characteristic.  This counterexample is an affine hypersurface which is not a binomial hypersurface.  What is wrong with the argument above?

Comment: This assertion is unjustified: "This action is simply the product of the actions ..." It is not even clear why $T_Y$ should be a torus.

Comment: Thank you @PiotrAchinger.